# Log aggregator/search reports?

Tags: logging, log-analysis

I may be getting the lingo wrong, but I'll explain my needs and I hope it becomes clear.

I get a daily report via email from Papertrail with a pre-defined search. This report gives me all logs from the past 24h about issues in production (again, a lot of stuff is already filtered out by the pre-defined search).

While I can go to Pepertrail and look at and search the logs for that period of time, I am finding difficult to actually see what is happening. By looking at it and scrolling I can spot repeated messages, sure, but I basically have to look at every message one by one. to try to spot a trend or something unusual.

Is there any simple tool out there which allows me to upload a log file and analyse it? I worked with the ELK stack before, but we are a small company and I don't think it would be worth our time to maintain it.

I would like it to group similar messages, for example, and tell me "these messages make up 60% of your logs". At the same time, I'd like to be able to see unique messages in the file, or something like this, so I can have a better idea of what is happening. For a better idea, my report is not big at all, rarely more than 2000 lines.

Does such a tool exist? Every log management tool I've seen and tried is not much more than a fancy log viewer, but none of them give me this visibility and insight about what I'm looking at.